# Comer TAG 60 gokart engine. How to troubleshoot ignition system

Tags: troubleshooting, stator

Does anyone know the voltage expected from the stator at a the rotations per minute given by the stater motor?

[image: from a shop]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Motorcycle stators can range from 20-100 VAC depending on engine speed, but not sure on a smaller motor like this.  Are you trying to diagnose a certain issue or is this really what you need to know? Edit: I see now that this is a very small engine - smaller than a lawn mower even.

Comment: Hi I did not see you comment sorry. Actually I have come to a point where I changed the stator, the CDI box, the ignition coil and I have two new spark plugs. All but the sparkplug is from the company Selettra. When I ask them how to troubleshoot the electric start system, they respond, that they do not give that kind of information.

My son have chosen to participate in a racetype which demands selettra ignition "Cadett junior Denmark".I think we need to reconsider this class.